# Find jQuery cache hit/miss from CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn

If you include jQuery from a CDN, is there a way to determine whether a user fetched the content from the CDN or retrieved it from their cache?

Obviously a cache hit doesn't make an HTTP request, but could you test that and report Javascript back to your own server with the data?

Comment: What is this for? I'm just thinking if you want to retrieve from http req every time you could add the current timestamp as a querystring variable which should force it to download again. E.g. `<script src="http://some.cdn.com/myscript.js?v=123456789"></script>`

Comment: I want to see whether it's worth it to load jQuery from a CDN. It would be great to have actual data instead of speculation about the percent of users with jQuery in their cache.

Comment: Oh I see :) fair enough.

Comment: Wondering if you could make an async request for a resource that should be cached, and then immediately try to request a variable from it... may only work if the script was loaded from the filesystem.

Comment: sounds like a fun exercise to me and 7 other people at least :-) did you ever get any stats on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use CHARLES or a similar debugging proxy to determine loading speed?

If you want to know the speed from a client's perspective from multiple locations, use http://www.webpagetest.org/ with two differing versions of your website (one with CDN, one with self-hosted static location) and compare the loading speeds. Personally, unless you have a lot of custom javascript code, it makes sense to use a CDN for jQuery, especially since lots of sites use the Google Libraries API for jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

If you have logging on your CDN (we don't seem to?) you could change the CDN url for test runs and also use a pingback url on your server.  Over a period of time, compare the ping back url hits and times with your CDN url hits and the unique visitors counts.

You should be able to get an idea about how many unique hits on your cdn url you get vs unique hits you get on your page.  The difference should be bots, scrapers and cached or failed loading of resources.  Bots you can eliminate, scrapers probably as well, so your %ages should be reflective over a long enough period.

Would this work for you?

We do this on non-cdn resources to see if people are downloading the latest CSS files or not to force a name change only on those IPs that seem to have cached a resource after a change was made to the css file.

Comment: It could work, but I'm thinking about using Google's CDN; we wouldn't be able to log from that.

Comment: No, but the test would give you an indication of how many use caching in general, which would likely work similarly for knowing how many use the CDN from google?  Beyond that, it's a very good point - not sure how you'd do that otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Testing for a 304 (not modified) would be difficult without using ajax. And using ajax will be very difficult unless you get around the same origin policy on the CDN.

I assume you want to test the actual time the scripts loads and becomes available on the clients, and would like to compare this data using CDN vs. something local. If so, wouldn’t it be better to test the actual time instead of doing some cache test?

It’s fairly easy to set up an A/B test of the actual time the scripts are loading.

For the **A** test you could do the CDN/local separation

```
<script>var _time = new Date().getTime();</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="project.js"></script>
<script>_time = new Date().getTime() - _time;</script>
```

And the **B** test a local script merge or whatever:

```
<script>var _time = new Date().getTime();</script>
<script src="project.includingjquery.min.js"></script>
<script>_time = new Date().getTime() - _time;</script>
```

Then report the `_time` variable into analytics or your own database using ajax. If the **B** users have lower `_time` reported, you know it’s the right way to go...

Answer (score 0):

If you were willing to add some bulk to a page to test this you could add an ajax request to a CDN for jQuery and then check the headers for a 304 response.  If you then create a second ajax request to ping back to your server telling you if jQuery was cached or not, i.e. if it was a 200 or a 304 response.  I haven't tried this but it should work, but it will add some extra requests for your users, but given the fact they'll be asynchronous it probably wouldn't have any impact.

Comment: Damnit after posting I realise this won't work unless the CDN you use has access control headers to allow cross domain ajax requests?  Does any one know if any CDNs set an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

Comment: Sadly, none of the three CDNs listed on the jQuery download page (Google, Microsoft and jQuery's own) support the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>var s=new Date().getTime();</script>
<script src="cdncontent"></script>
<script>
var s = new Date().getTime() - s;
if (s < 100) {
  //likely from cache
} else {
  //likely from CDN
}
</script>
```

Comment: the time of 25ms is only a guess, that you're unlikely to actually connect, request and download the given file in under 25ms, but that *should* be enough to load/parse from local... you may want to tweak/test this a bit.

Answer (score -2):

It always worth loading resources from a CDN. The only drawback is whether the CDN is geographically close to the user or not. You need to check your target audience and decide if it's better to use it or not. In case of jquery, I always use Google CDN which I think is realiable and robust.

Comment: This answer has no data attached to it. For example, right now we bundle minified jQuery with other Javascript in one file. Splitting out jQuery would involve an extra HTTP request. I can't evaluate that tradeoff unless I know how many users already have the file in the cache.

Comment: You'll always have an extra request per element anyway, the big difference is between making requests to the same server or different servers. Let's say you have both resources in the same server, your server would get 2 requests but it would serve one after the other one. On the other hand if you have 2 resources coming from different servers, ideally, both resources would be served at the same time and therefore displayed quickly.

Comment: This answer makes wrong assumptions. Minifying the jQuery source together with other scripts into one single file/request is arguable faster than serving two requests, no matter where they are located.